# Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYZE: Total time greatly exceeds sum of parts

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a python script that receives external events and writes them to Postgres database.
Most of the time INSERT operates quite fast (< 0.3 sec). But sometimes query execution time exceeds 10-15 seconds! There are about 500 events per minute and such a slow behavior is unacceptable.

The query is simple:

```
INSERT INTO tests (...) VALUES (...)
```

The table (has about 5 million records) is quite simple too:
[image: Table tests]

I've added 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE' before 'INSERT' in my script and it gives me this:

```
Insert on tests  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.051..0.051 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.014 ms
Execution time: 15624.374 ms
```

How can this be possible? How can I find out what is it doing these 15 seconds?

I'm using Windows server and Postgres 9.6. Script and Postgres are on the same machine.

Additionally I've collected Windows Performance Counter's data during this (disk queue length, Processor time) and it showed nothing.

This server is virtual server on VMWare ESXi, but I don't know what can I examine in it about this situation.

### Added

These queries are running in multiple threads (several parallel scripts do that).
`INSERT` is done without explicit transaction.
There is no triggers (there was a trigger, but I removed it and nothing changed) and no foreign keys.

> What if you execute it a second time?

this query is executed in several scripts about 400 times a minute (total). And most of the time it executes quickly. I cannot catch this long execution time in query tool.

I will definitely try to look into `pg_stat_activity` next time I'll see this, thanks.

Comment: Any triggers on the table? Or many foreign keys? I think you should see the timing for those using `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: What if you execute it a second time?

Comment: Are all of your indexes BTREE?

Comment: Is the INSERT done without explicit transactions?  That is, in "autocommit" mode?

Comment: Is there possibly some other transaction holding a lock that conflicts with this insert?

Comment: If you can catch it  in pg_stat_activity in the act of being slow, then the wait_event column  for that row has a good chance of telling you the problem.

Comment: Do not use explain analyze to catch the time of the query. Simply enable \timing in psql and then run query without analyze. Refer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3148/how-can-i-time-sql-queries-using-psql

Comment: `These queries are running in multiple threads (several parallel scripts do that).` You are locking yourself out.

Comment: There are about 11 scripts running simultaneously. They are waiting for incoming events and add them to database table. I can understand that it can be locking there, but not for 15 seconds!